# Logging everything to diagnose random shut downs

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, logging, diagnostic

My laptop started randomly shutting down. For example, I'm skyping and then -boom- all of the sudden the screen goes black and it has shut down. Once I restart it, everything seems to work as normal. This has happened a few times now, but I can't spot any pattern. The laptop, at least externally, doesn't seem to overheat and it's a newer model, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Thus I would like to start a process that logs, say, every half a second, everything that there is to log regarding the laptop, meaning, temperature of the CPU, SSD, the memory consumption, all the running processes etc. You name it!
*Are the any tools for this?*
Thus, when it shuts down again, I hope to figure be able to figure out what happened by looking at the log and hopefully seeing a pattern immediately before the shut down. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally journal ist stored in /run/log/journal meaning it is not persistent.

but you can enable it. In /etc/systemd/journald.conf

```
storage=persistent
```

[source](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html)

```
journalctl --list-boots
```

show's you how many boots are stored. the previous boot has always 
number -1

```
journalctl -b -1
```

show's you the journal from previous boot.

For more output in /etc/systemd/system.conf set

```
LogLevel=info
```

Or even

```
LogLevel=debug
```

very much output

Comment: my `run/log` folder is empty, though...

Comment: It is in`/run/log/journal/`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a point here, but even before I do anything to make it persistent, shouldn't there be something in `run/log`? There is no `journal` subfolder there (not even hidden), it's just empty ...

Comment: `ps -p 1 -o comm=` andi `journalctl --list-boots` also `lsb_release -rd`  and it is /run/log  `ls -al /run/log/`