# After last update my Ubuntu 20.04.1 became unbootable

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates

A few days ago I run upgrade procedure (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`). It seems that a new kernel was installed: `5.4.0-52-generic`. After reboot my laptop hangs. I'm only able to run it using previous kernel: `5.4.0-51-generic`.

How can I investigate what's went wrong with `5.4.0-52-generic` kernel and fix it?

Comment: The same: unbootable, kernel panic on inability to mount root FS - but I don't afford to reproduce now.

Answer (score 1):

removing plymouthsplash, then you can see messages from bootprozess.
[How to remove plymouth slash during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98566/how-do-deactivate-plymouth-boot-screen)

another way make persistent journal.[relevant](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts/871231#871231)

for loglevel look
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203632/logging-everything-to-diagnose-random-shut-downs/1203641#1203641)